# Filter or ignore a list of directories based on path

Tags: bash, git

I have the following command to find files that have changed in a branch compared to `master`.

```
git --no-pager diff --diff-filter=AM --name-status --no-renames $(git merge-base ${1:-master} HEAD)
```

This gives me an output similar to below:

```
M       platform/team-a/dev/module/submodule/file.py
M       platform/team-b/prod/module/config.yaml
A       README.md
```

Ideally I'd like to ignore files that have changed in the root. In the above example I'd want to ignore the `README.md` as I'm only really concerned with files under `platform/`.

My full code looks like so, with omissions:

```sh
while read -r status file; do
  case $status in
    A)
        DIRNAME="$(dirname "${file}")" && \
        echo file in $$DIRNAME was created && \
        cd $$DIRNAME && \
        # do something
        ;;
    M)
        DIRNAME="$(dirname "${file}")" && \
        echo file in $$DIRNAME was modified && \
        cd $$DIRNAME && \
        # do something
        ;;
    esac
  done < <(git --no-pager diff --diff-filter=AM --name-status --no-renames $(git merge-base ${1:-master} HEAD) | sort -k 1,1)
```

> $$VAR is a GCP cloud build convention

It would be good if maybe the ignore list was configurable easily, so I could say if file in `['.', 'docs/', 'platform/designs'] then skip` as an example.

My bash skills are minimal so not sure best way to approach this, otherwise I'd write a dirty if statement in the while loop.

Comment: Try `-- platform` in the end.

Comment: @ElpieKay brilliant that works so far. Whats this called so I can read up?

Comment: It's just the path option supported by git commands. See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-ltpathgt82308203. As to the `--`, see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcli#_description.

Comment: Happy to accept it as an answer if you want to write something up

Comment: extra note : run `git help <command>` to get the reference documentation for that command. For example : the page linked by ElpieKay is the content of `git help diff`

Comment: Side note: `git diff` can compute the merge base for you, using the three-dot syntax: `git diff <options> master...HEAD` is more or less equivalent to `git diff <options> $(git merge-base master HEAD)`. Note that this is a special feature of `git diff`; other commands that take the three-dot syntax use it differently.